# ReportViewer RDLC Chart Gap

Tags: c#, graph, charts, reportviewer, rdlc

I've got two chart types sharing one chart area. One of the charts is a smooth area chart (three of this type are generated but only one is shown in the designer), the other is a column chart.

The purpose of the column chart is to indicate where some limits are located on the smooth area chart. The charts are created well except that the smooth area chart has gaps where the limit lines show up.

How do I get rid of the gaps that are occurring? The following images are print screens of my issue.

Thanks

[image: 2D Representation]

[image: 3D Representation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the column chart data is included in the C# list that I'm using as a data source for these charts. So, when making the smooth area graphs it is using those red lines values as a data point, causing a gap because they're y value is set to 0. There is no gap, just a 0 value.

The column chart y values are actually a different parameter with a random name but using the same dataset, since the smooth area chart doesn't have that value set, they are effectively 0, so you don't see them show up as columns.

The real problem is that I basically need to show data conditionally, or get two datasets in one chart.

Comment: Turns out that when you export to PDF (which is the only time these charts will be seen) you can overlap separate charts. So I put the column data into a different chart and overlapped it with the smooth area chart. All is good!